# Select Column within a Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

THE QUESTION:  For all 300 level courses (300-399), list the course number, prerequisite course number and prerequisite course description.

Sorry if this is tricky to understand, I just don't even know how to phrase my question. Basically, I'm trying to figure out this question and I have absolutely no idea where to start when it comes to listing the prerequisite descriptions.

I only need to show the prerequisite description that relates with the main course.

Below is what I have so far, definitely not complete. The link is an example of the output of a `SELECT *` query to the Course table.

Just to clarify: every `Course_NO` has a prerequisite listed. However, the prerequisite is also a `Course_NO` listed in the Course table.

Thanks for any help in advance, I appreciate it!

[image: Example Course Table]

```
SELECT  
    Course_No, 
    Prerequisite
FROM COURSE
WHERE
    Course_NO < 400
    AND Course_NO >= 300
```

Comment: Hi Hilary, welcome to Stack Oveflow. Can you please refrain from using images in this manner and enter some of the sample data. Image links might die and with the code here we can always refer back to it, should somebody have the same problem

Comment: Can a course have more than 1 prereq?

Comment: No, just one prereq per course

Comment: This looks like a typical recursive cte. There are thousands of examples across SO to do this and millions around the internet. It is a basic hierarchy type of problem (like an organizational chart).

Comment: Ok thanks I will search recursive, I just didn't even know what to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Often times the hardest part is figuring out the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is use a table alias C1 for the original query. I would then sub-query the course description for the prerequisite course number, using a table alias C2. Notice I use both table alias- C1 and C2- associating the C2.Course_No number with the C1.PREREQUISITE number. The C2.DESCRIPTION is selected from this subquery. The subquery is given a column alias [Prerequisite Course Description]; note that without a column alias the field would have a blank header.

Should you use recursion? In this case you are probably not supposed to attempt such a solution unless you are specifically told to do so.

```
  SELECT C1.Course_No 
        ,C1.PREREQUISITE, 
        ,(SELECT C2.DESCRIPTION 
            FROM COURSE AS C2 
           WHERE C2.Course_No = C1.PREREQUISITE
         ) AS [Prerequisite Course Description]
   FROM COURSE AS C1
  WHERE C1.Course_NO < 400
        C1.AND Course_NO >= 300
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as a [self join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT  
    MainCourse.Course_No, 
    PreRequisiteCourse.Description as PreRequisiteDescription
FROM COURSE as MainCourse
Inner Join Course as PreRequisiteCourse
on MainCourse.Prerequisite = PreRequisiteCourse.Course_No
WHERE
    MainCourse.Course_NO Between 300 And 399
```

If you have some courses with no Prerequisite that you want to include in the results, you should change the `Inner join` to a `Left Outer Join`.